# bind sql xml to gridview in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-widget

I've got a basic Andriod app that has a button and a gridview on it.  When the button is clicked, the app calls a web service and retrieves a sql-xml string from it (C#, Dataset.GetXML()), which all works great.  I need to know how to bind the GridView control to this sql:xml to display the data.  I know it's got something to do with a type of Adapter but I can't figure it out.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

@lyricsboy:
Here's a copy of the XML that comes back from the web service (keep in mind that this is a Web Service that I built in .NET so if any changes to that need to be made, they can):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<string xmlns="RemoteWebService">
<AllContacts> 
  <Table>
    <ContactID>7</ContactID> 
    <ContactName>Support</ContactName> 
    <EmailAddress>me@me.com</EmailAddress> 
    <CCEmail>him@me.com</CCEmail> 
    <Visible>true</Visible> 
    <Description>If you have concerns you can use this email. </Description> 
 </Table>
 <Table>
   <ContactID>8</ContactID> 
   <ContactName>Training</ContactName> 
   <EmailAddress>them@me.com</EmailAddress> 
   <CCEmail />
   <Visible>true</Visible> 
   <Description>This email is designated for Training issues.</Description>
 </Table>
</AllContacts>
</string>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you'll need to parse the XML into something that you can give to an adapter. If the data sets are of a reasonable size, you can use model objects of your own design to hold the data. Create an ArrayList of them, and pass them off to `ArrayAdapter` or a subclass of your own design (or your own custom Adapter if you need it).

Based on the sample XML, I would create a `Contact` class that had fields you could use to store all of the data you send for each item. Then write some code that uses `XmlPullParser` ([docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html)) to turn your XML into `Contact` instances and put them in an `ArrayList`. Pass that list to an `ArrayAdapter` that you then pass to the `GridView`.

Comment: WOW...being new to all this, it seems like a whole lot just to perform a simple task (not doubting your method btw).  So would this be the case for ANY xml that comes from a web service?  Sounds like there is not a way to take an XML file that you may not be aware of the contents and display it in a GridView, correct?

Comment: At least not with the built-in APIs. There may be some third party code that can do that, but it would be hard to do in a generic way that was also high performance across the wide range of devices Android supports.

Comment: So is this the preferred way to handle data from a database (to display in a GridView) or are there better/more preferred approaches?  Of the datasets that I work with, 95% of them return < 1000 records.  I know there's more than 1 way to skin a cat but just looking for the most common way.

Comment: What is probably more common with data sets that large is to store the data in a similar database schema on the local device. Populate the database using web service calls and marshaling code, then query the local database to populate the UI. This way you get to take advantage of the whole `Cursor` and `ContentProvider` ecosystem if you want to.